# How is Deep linking in an expo-managed mobile app functioning on iOS but not on android?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking, mobile-application

I have a react-native/expo mobile app that I am trying to develop a sharing feature for. I am generating urls inside the mobile app to be used to open up the app and redirect to content. Right now it works exactly as expected with iOS (testing on testflight) but does not work at all on android (testing on Google Play internal testing). I have been modifying everything I have access to the configuration of but nothing seems to impact the functionality. On iOS when the link is engaged with it opens up the default browser and then immediately opens up the app. On android it just opens up the default browser and does not open up the app.

Both the assetlinks.json and apple-app-site-association file are uploaded correctly to the correct domain inside the .well-known folder. The assetlinks.json has the correct package name and sha256 fingerprints (confirmed through the Google Developer digital-asset-link tool).

is a placeholder for my domain

In my app.js in my react-native Linking config:
`prefixes: ['https://<domain>.org', 'https://www.<domain>.org'],`

In my app.json file I am trying to handle all possible ways that the browser handles the url:

```js
"intentFilters": [
{
    "action": "VIEW",
    "data": [{
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "www.<domain>.org",
        "pathPrefix": "/mobile"
    }],
    "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
    },
    {
    "action": "VIEW",
    "data": [{
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "<domain>.org",
        "pathPrefix": "/mobile"
    }],
    "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
    },
    {
    "action": "VIEW",
    "data": [{
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "www.<domain>.org",
        "pathPrefix": "/mobile/*"
    }],
    "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
    },
    {
    "action": "VIEW",
    "data": [{
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "<domain>.org",
        "pathPrefix": "/mobile/*"
    }],
    "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
    }
]
```

The urls I am generating look like:

```js
https://<domain>.org/mobile?mykey=myvalue&mykey2=myvalue2
```

I have exhausted my ideas for values I can test that could impact the functionality. This is my first time setting up deep linking in an app and I definitely could have missed something that is required to work on android. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried:

- Toggling the links generated to have a trailing / after the base url. e.g. .org/mobile/ vs .org/mobile
- Handling all of the different url setups of www..org vs .org and the trailing / in the intentFilters in the app.json
- Confirmed the link between the package name/sha256 fingerprint and the app package name using the Google Developer Digital Asset Link tool: (Success! Host .org grants app deep linking to com..app) works with and without the www.
- Tested deep linking without including pathPrefixes (just for testing) to see if it will open up any url at all at that domain in the mobile app. Even without the pathPrefix the app would not open on android